# TYPO3 - Redirecting to login page when user is not logged in

Tags: redirect, authentication, typo3, typoscript

I have some restricted pages built in Typo3. The problem is I cannot automatically redirect user from these pages to login page. How do I do that? I desperately need it and cannot find a solution despite of the fact I have spent most of the day working on it :(

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Typo3: 404 for restricted access page instead of login form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663228/typo3-404-for-restricted-access-page-instead-of-login-form)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That should work fine:

```
# Restricted area starts at pid 123.
# Check if user is logged in:
[PIDinRootline = 123] && [usergroup = *]
# do something
[else]
page.config >
page.config.additionalHeaders = Location: http://www.yourdomain.org/login.html
[end]
```

[Found here](http://blog.team-noir.net/2010/11/how-to-redirect-restricted-typo3-pages-to-loginform-and-back/)

Comment: @Mateng: Your condition is wrong and ends up in an infinite loop (of redirects). Use `[PIDinRootline = 123] && [loginUser = ]` and remove the `[else]`.

Comment: **Notice:** Do not restrict the complete page, only all contents of the page. Otherwise RealURL will trigger the 404 handler before redirect takes place.

See [404 for restricted access page instead of login form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663228/typo3-404-for-restricted-access-page-instead-of-login-form/25649993) for other solutions.

Comment: In addition, don't use option "User Group Access Rights" when you want to work with this TS solution

Answer (score 1):

Just for reasons of documentation: make sure you choose the right redirect mode.

If I wish to redirect for a certain page after login, but only one specific user group should redirect to another page, then I choose two items for redirect and bring them to the right order. I choose them under page > Plugin > Redirect.

The order should be the way that the specific conditions are caught first.

This screenshot illustrates it:

[image: Redirect options]

This was tested for Typo3 6.1.3.

Hope that helps sb...

Comment: The question was about redirecting if not logged in. Your answer is about redirecting AFTER login, right? I think you should separate the 2 things. Especially since this already very confusing with several questions existing and some answers are outdated.

Answer (score 1):

For newer Typo3 versions (e.g. v11) the accepted answer doesn't work because the error page is pulled up before the TypoScript is executed. Instead, use Typo3's error handling (Sites > Error Handling) to show content from your Login page when encountering a 403 Forbidden.[image]