# How to define redirect page for protected pages

Tags: typo3

In a TYPO3 6.1 site, I would like to make the creation of restricted (fe_groups) pages as easy as possible for editors. There's not one single protected area, but several protected pages all over the pagetree.

What I would like to achieve would be that whenever a page has some login behaviour/restriction and no valid fe_user is logged in, there is a redirection to a central login page.

I have found this post
[TYPO3 - Redirecting to login page when user is not logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141580/typo3-redirecting-to-login-page-when-user-is-not-logged-in) that refers to the same issue - but the solution requires setting PIDs by hand.

I can hardly believe that such a feature ("set target page for redirections based on access restrictions") is not available. Or does it exist, or is it on a roadmap somewhere? And if not, is there a workaround?

Comment: Also You could try custom 404 page https://axelerant.com/redirect-to-login-for-access-denied-typo3-users/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a big missing feature in TYPO3. The problem is that because of the way TYPO3 is built it's hard to determine whether a page doesn't exist (404) or access is forbidden (403). I did some further development of an unpublished extension that does the job, see https://github.com/phluzern/adfc_pagenotfound

In readme.txt you will find the configuration that is needed. It is in use with TYPO3 4.7, therefore some used classes may be deprecated or removed in 6.1. If so, fork the project, change them and make some pull requests so I can update it.

The extension makes use of a custom parameter $arPid (access restriction pid). The ID to the page that is access restricted is sent to the login page. Your login form must be able to handle this parameter in order to redirect, see an example here:
https://github.com/phluzern/phzldap/blob/master/pi1/class.tx_phzldap_pi1.php#L133

It might be better to use a redirect_url as it is supported in felogin.

**Update**

In the meantime, I'm using an improved class with the following features:

- If access to page is forbidden, redirect to a login page with the standard `redirect_url` parameter. This allows a redirect after a successful fe login using EXT:felogin without modifications and also supports speaking URLs.
- Redirect to 404 page if page is not found respecting the current language of the site.

The code is as follows:

```
<?php

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;

class user_pageNotFound {
    /**
     * Detect language and redirect to 404 error page
     *
     * @param array $params "currentUrl", "reasonText" and "pageAccessFailureReasons"
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Controller\TypoScriptFrontendController $tsfeObj
     */
    public function pageNotFound($params, $tsfeObj) {
        /*
         * If a non-existing page with a RealURL path was requested (www.mydomain.tld/foobar), a fe_group value for an empty
         * key is set:
         * $params['pageAccessFailureReasons']['fe_group'][null] = 0;
         * This is the reason why the second check was implemented.
         */
        if (!empty($params['pageAccessFailureReasons']['fe_group']) && !array_key_exists(null, $params['pageAccessFailureReasons']['fe_group'])) {
            // page access failed because of missing permissions
            header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
            $this->initTSFE(1);
            /** @var \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer $cObj */
            $cObj = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\ContentObject\\ContentObjectRenderer');
            $loginUrl = $cObj->typoLink_URL(array(
                'parameter' => $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageNotFound_handling_loginPageID'],
                'useCacheHash' => FALSE,
                'forceAbsoluteUrl' => TRUE,
                'additionalParams' => '&redirect_url=' . $params['currentUrl']
            ));
            TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\HttpUtility::redirect($loginUrl);
        } else {
            // page not found
            // get first realurl configuration array (important for multidomain)
            $realurlConf = array_shift($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']);
            // look for language configuration
            foreach ($realurlConf['preVars'] as $conf) {
                if ($conf['GETvar'] == 'L') {
                    foreach ($conf['valueMap'] as $k => $v) {
                        // if the key is empty (e.g. default language without prefix), break
                        if (empty($k)) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        // we expect a part like "/de/" in requested url
                        if (GeneralUtility::isFirstPartOfStr($params['currentUrl'], '/' . $k . '/')) {
                            $tsfeObj->pageErrorHandler('/index.php?id=' . $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageNotFound_handling_redirectPageID'] . '&L=' . $v);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // handle default language
            $tsfeObj->pageErrorHandler('/index.php?id=' . $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageNotFound_handling_redirectPageID']);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Initializes a TypoScript Frontend necessary for using TypoScript and TypoLink functions
     *
     * @param int $id
     * @param int $typeNum
     */
    protected function initTSFE($id = 1, $typeNum = 0) {
        \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Utility\EidUtility::initTCA();
        if (!is_object($GLOBALS['TT'])) {
            $GLOBALS['TT'] = new \TYPO3\CMS\Core\TimeTracker\NullTimeTracker;
            $GLOBALS['TT']->start();
        }

        $GLOBALS['TSFE'] = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Controller\\TypoScriptFrontendController',  $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS'], $id, $typeNum);
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_page = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Page\\PageRepository');
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_page->init(TRUE);
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->connectToDB();
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->initFEuser();
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->determineId();
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->initTemplate();
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->rootLine = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_page->getRootLine($id, '');
        $GLOBALS['TSFE']->getConfigArray();

        if (\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::isLoaded('realurl')) {
            $rootline = \TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Utility\BackendUtility::BEgetRootLine($id);
            $host = \TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Utility\BackendUtility::firstDomainRecord($rootline);
            $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = $host;
        }
    }

}
```

The only thing you need to configure are the PIDs of the page not found and login pages:

```
// ID of the page to redirect to if page was not found
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageNotFound_handling_redirectPageID'] = 4690;
// ID of the page to redirect to if current page is access protected
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageNotFound_handling_loginPageID'] = 5404;
```

Comment: No, it's just too hacky. The whole process to find out whether a page is not present or not accessible would need to be reworked. Maybe you could open an issue on forge nevertheless and describe the missing feature.

Comment: Did that. http://forge.typo3.org/issues/53813 I hope it's ok that I referred to our conversation here

Comment: Thanks lorenz for providing this base.
We have updated it and created a pull request. Beside that, we added the information to https://forge.typo3.org/issues/53813

Comment: I just added the way I'm currently doing it since I abandoned the use of EXT:adfcpagenotfound in the meantime. I no longer work for the maintainer of this extension but I hope they will merge your request.