# TYPO3 Redirect to requested page after login

Tags: redirect, authentication, typo3, http-status-code-403

Coming from [Typo3: 404 for restricted access page instead of login form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663228/typo3-404-for-restricted-access-page-instead-of-login-form/32697174#32697174) the answer of Bharat Parmar was leading me into the right direction but now I'm stuck.

I want to add a link to a restricted page. If a visitor clicks on it, the login page should appear (I used the extension pagenotfoundhandling as Bharat Parmar suggested). This works! But after login the user is not redirected to the originally requested page but to the standard welcome page of the restricted area (defined in FE Login Plugin).

I can't get it to work to redirect to the originally requested page after login. It always takes the user to the redirection page that was set in the Frontend Login Plugin settings.

Unfortunatly, I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment so I have to ask a new question.

Can anybody help? Or if Bharat Parmar reads this, can you give me a hint how you did it?

Thanks in advance!

Update

Thanks to @lorenz for the hint, I finally got a solution.

https://github.com/web-vision/adfc_pagenotfound

It's a new, updated version for TYPO3 6.2 and it works!!!

1. Download the folder from Github as ZIP
2. unzip
3. rename folder with extension files in it to adfc_pagenotfound (without -master)
4. upload to typo3conf/ext directory
5. install the extension "adfc_pagenotfound" in TYPO3 extention manager
6. add 'AdditionalConfiguration.php' File in typo3conf directory and change ID in file
7. in TYPO3 FE Plugin choose "Defined by Get / Post variables"
8. Done!

Comment: Please check my answer in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20093865/1517316) (see "Update") for a suitable solution respecting RealURL and languages.

Comment: Thanks @lorenz , but I'm using TYPO3 6.2, I don't think that this solution is suitable for this version... $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE'] doesn't exist anymore. Can I translate it to `return array(
 'FE' => array(
  'pageNotFound_handling_redirectPageID' => '100',
  'explicitADmode' => '200',
 ),
 ...
)` And sorry, I have no idea where to add this class... Any further help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: I found a solution and put it in the update section above.

Comment: Usually you will put such configuration to your AdditionalConfiguration.php. But it looks as if you found it out!