# TYPO3 not logged in show login page and not 404 page

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, felogin

I'm running a TYPO3 page with frontend user login.

If a user is not logged in and he clicks on a page that is only visible for logged in users at the moment I got 404 page.

How can I display the a different page then the 404 page?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
Tried it this way

```
[PIDinRootline = 68] && [usergroup = *]
# do something
[else]
page.config >
page.config.additionalHeaders = Location: http://www.yourdomain.org/login.html
[end]
```

but then all pages redirects (run into else branch)

**Update:**

also tried:

```
[globalVar = TSFE:id=68] && [usergroup = *]
# do something
[else]
page.config >
page.config.additionalHeaders = Location: http://www.yourdomain.org/login.html
[end]
```

=> also not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TYPO3 - Redirecting to login page when user is not logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141580/typo3-redirecting-to-login-page-when-user-is-not-logged-in)

Comment: @pixeldesu the mentioned solution produces an infinity loop ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663228/typo3-404-for-restricted-access-page-instead-of-login-form

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TYPO3: 404 for restricted access page instead of login form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663228/typo3-404-for-restricted-access-page-instead-of-login-form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats the working solution:

```
[globalVar = TSFE:id =68] && [loginUser = ]
page.config >
page.config.additionalHeaders = Location: http://www.yourdomain.org/login.html
[end]
```

Answer (score 2):

The [marked solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48946482/4274248) does not work anymore in TYPO3 v9. Firstly, in v9 the condition syntax changed *(although the old syntax is marked only as deprecated and still works)* as well as the way in which the `additionalHeaders` need to be configured. The code in the answer would need to be

```
[getTSFE().id == 68 && loginUser('*') == false]
    page.config >
    page.config.additionalHeaders.10 {
        header = Location: http://www.yourdomain.org/login.html
    }
[END]
```

However, **this does still not seem to be a working solution for the asked question!** The code works only for a *non-access-restricted page called with no active login.* When calling an *access-restricted page without being logged in,* the 403 Forbidden error will be returned and the above code will be ignored. This behaviour will either show the default 404 page (when `['FE']['pageNotFound_handling']` is set in LocalConfiguration.php) or whatever is defined in the [Site Management Error Handling](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/ErrorHandling.html).

My workaround has been to create a 403 page with a link to the login form and, via the above mentioned Site Management Error Handling, define what happens in case of a 403 error.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use an extension like e.g. `pagenotfoundhandling`. See: https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/pagenotfoundhandling/

There you can select a page (e.g. the page with login) to display when the user lands on a restricted page.

Comment: is there a typoscript solution as well?